# Submitting form upon selecting value, how do I recognize the submit event in my form processing

Tags: php, forms

I have a simple form that has a select dropdown menu. Upon selection of an item from the menu, I cause a form submit...the code that does this is:

```
<select name="some name" onchange="this.form.submit"></select>
```

Now if this form was being submitted using a submit button(say name="submitForm") then I would simply do this:

`if($_POST['submitForm'] == 'submit')` and then go about doing the processing that is dependent on the form submit.

However, since there is no submit button per say, how do I get the equivalent of $_POST['some name'] == 'submit' ? (This is obviously not correct)

THanks much !

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden input field named `submitForm` and value `submit` *inside* the `<form></form>` tags.

```
<input type="hidden" name="submitForm" value="submit" />
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have a form like below, let say in `index.php`

```
    <form method='POST' action="index.php">
        <input type='text' name='input1' />
        <input type='submit' name='test' style="display: none;" />
        <select id="selSubmit" name='submit_option' onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        </select>
     </form>
```

To check if a form is submitted you can check if a field is not empty `$_POST['one of the field'] != ''` rather that the normal submit `$_POST['name of form']`.

```
     <?php 
        if($_POST['input1'] != '') || $_POST['submit_option'] != ''){
             print_r($_POST);
        }

     ?>
```

or you can have a hidden field with a defined value as suggested by Bibhas.

Answer (score 0):

Check for all your other buttons in $_POST. If none of them were sent, it means JS was used to submit the form. Simple as that. :)

Comment: is this JS doing this? My thinking was this is dom scripting...also, the selected value of the drop down, I can echo that out, which means the form was being submitted

Answer (score 0):

you can create a hidden field which can be posted say name = "processMode" value = "Partial|Submit"